# Why does this curl fail, when the site loads fine in a browser?

Tags: curl

I'm trying to run `curl https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/google.com` to get the results of which DNS endpoints fail for certain servers (in this example, google.com). The site works fine in a browser, but my curl command returns a 404.

I'm not super well versed in curl, so I assume there's something I'm just doing wrong here.

Comment: Works fine for me. Did you use the exact URL you posted above?

Comment: Yes, I get `<title>404 Page Not Found - What's My DNS?</title>`

Comment: Hm, nevermind - looks like there's a firewall rule blocking on the host I was on. Tried it from another machine, and it seems to have worked.